# Validate the JDBC request with a user defined variable

Tags: jmeter

I am new to JMeter,

In my test I am creating a JDBC Connection to oracle DB and running a query which fetching me the count of records, which I want to validate must be equal to the `SAMPLE-NUMBER` (which is a defined variable in the user defined variable).

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM event_log WHERE audit_context_key LIKE '288017ec-0dcf-4fd5-9565-e8ad15e65cd2' AND event_desc = 'Success'
```

Response Body:

```
COUNT(*)
2
```

[UserDefined Variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BstQk.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this, defined the variable name in JDBC request,

for example, `TOTALCOUNT` and add a `JSR223` Assertion with the following code,

```
1.upto(vars.get('TOTALCOUNT_#') as int, {
    if (vars.get('TOTALCOUNT_' + it) == '${__groovy(vars.get('SAMPLE-NUMBER'),)}') {
        AssertionResult.setFailure(false);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

[Response Assertion](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/response-assertions-in-jmeter-32-new-and-improved) can do the trick for you:

1. In the [JDBC Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request) define "Variable Names", i.e. `ACTUAL_COUNT`

   [image]
2. Once done you can compare the `ACTUAL_COUNT` [variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) value with the `SAMPLE-NUMBER` variable like:

   [image]